# Prevent vertical overlapping of sub-menu list items

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, padding

I have a nested unordered list functioning as a sub-menu however the list items of the sub-menu are overlapping. It appears that padding of the links are overlapping:

```css
ul {
  padding: 12px 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.selected-language {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.language-list {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
ul.language-list li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.language-list li a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li class="language-selection">
    <a title="foo" href="#" class="selected-language">
      <span>bar</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="language-list">
      <li>
        <a title="foo" href="#">
          <span>bar</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="foo" href="#">
          <span>bar</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I prevent the overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have `padding:10px` on a inline level `<a>` element I think. Try to set it as `display:block`, so it will render the `padding` correctly.

```
ul.language-list li a {
  ...
  display: block;
}
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 12px 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.selected-language {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.language-list {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}
ul.language-list li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.language-list li a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block; /*added*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li>Menu Item</li>
  <li class="language-selection">
    <a title="foo" href="#" class="selected-language">
      <span>bar</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="language-list">
      <li>
        <a title="foo" href="#">
          <span>bar</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a title="foo" href="#">
          <span>bar</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bingo and d'oh! Thanks.